# Force Excel to Use English Formula Formatting

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Is there a way to force excel to use English formulas? This is the first time I have gotten a language based issue because I don't normally have my sheets being used by users of another language.

I have a form that is basically one giant table. Visibility to certain rows is calculated and defined with a TRUE or FALSE statement on a hidden column and refreshed on a button press or certain cell changes.

I had a Spanish user open the file recently and everything was hidden due to the TRUE being displayed as VERDADERO. The VBA cannot find TRUE and thus nothing is considered TRUE and everything is hidden.

Is there a valid way around this? I can't think of a quick and easy way to patch this up.

Cheers!

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the code that is malfunctioning.

Answer (score 1):

Have the formula return `"TRUE"` or `"FALSE"` (i.e. a `String` rather than a `Boolean`) then it won't be translated.

It sounds like you're comparing a bool to a string anyway which is why the comparison fails in your code.

*alternatively:*

Format the cell as a number so that it returns `1` or `0` instead and compare to that.

The issue here isn't necessarily the translation but more the way you're comparing the value in your code.

Comment: Good answer - don't leave any interpretations to Excel, just force return what you're looking for!

Comment: The VBA isnt set to lookup a string, it actually uses the boolean value so it is a bit of a mind twister. I'll do some serious re-programming and testing tomorrow. In the meantime, I definitely have a new found respect for localisation teams.

Comment: @JaayB yes sorry I mean that I think your code is doing something like `If Range(“A1”).Value = “TRUE” Then` in which case it’s comparing a string. (Related note - posting the code might help ;) )